# How to include result of RC circuit at t = 0?

Tags: circuit-analysis

For the answer to the problem below, if I want to include the result at t = 0 as well should I write it as?

[image]

I don't know if it's possible to combine them into one expression only.

Here is the problem:

[image]
[image]

Comment: The initial condition has already been included in the solution. Let t=0 and the solution gives \$v_0 = 5\$

Comment: @Chu how would you get 5V there? The function u(t) is undefined at t = 0. If you substitute t = 0 into that expression you would get 25u(0) which is not defined.

Comment: Hum ... definition of the step function ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function

Comment: @Antonio51 so do you agree or disagree?

Comment: The Laplace model of the charged capacitor is a voltage source of 5 V in series with 10/s. This can be converted to a current source of 0.5 A in parallel with 10/s.

Comment: @Chu yes but what is the problem? It's correct already.

Comment: Agree. See my answer. At t=0, it is a point.

Comment: The initial condition is represented by the 0.5 A impulse in the 2nd circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Maple sheet to search result.
Write the 3 equations and solve (? not clear).

[image]

Now clear, if we see that ! **Red full curve**.

[image]

**So, you are right ...**

You can also write it, if **defined** **u(0)=0.5**, [as stated in this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function) and [this link](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeavisideStepFunction.html#:%7E:text=The%20Heaviside%20step%20function%20is,function%20or%20a%20generalized%20function.), "piecewise function".

[image]
\$ Vo(t) = 10*e(-1*t)+15*e(-2*t))u(t>0) + 10*u(0)\$.

Remember that, in fact, the full curve is a **point (5V)** and the equation !
Heaviside Step u(t) is defined for t > 0 -> So, it is **not defined for t=0**, it is a **discontinued** function.

Comment: I solved it and got the same result but the question is about including the value at t = 0 instead.

Comment: ok, I add in answer.

Comment: I think you made a mistake in your final expression as V(0) = 10 + 15u(0) + 10u(0) = 10 +25u(0) = 10+25*0.5 = 22.5V` instead of 5V. Anyway that is not important as I know how to do that. However, is combining things like this common? This problem is a bit special as the delta function make the voltage across the capacitor discontinuous which doesn't happen in real life.

Comment: In fact, it is not really a "mistake". I tried to explain that the first point is 10*u(t=0) (with the definition of u(0)=0.5. The equation Vo(t)=10∗e(−1∗t)+15∗e(−2∗t))u(t) must be plot as is. And it begin with 25 at t=10^(-50) ... So u(t) is the Heaviside function ... for t >0. u(0) is only a "mathematical" value for dis-continuous function.

Comment: I see but writing that way is mathematically wrong unless you explicitly saing that u(0) is a different function or using a different symbol to avoid confusion.

Comment: No. I think that u(0) is valid because it is the value (0.5 chosen by definition) of the discontinued "Heaviside" function at t=0. Step Heaviside function is only defined for t>0 or t<0. So Vo(t) for t=0 is not equal to 25. It is only the limit for t-->0 but not t=0. It is not "mathematically" the same "thing".

Answer (score -2):

In Figure 16.8, all the components and signals are Laplace transforms. In particular, the 0.5 A current source is an impulse, and this represents the initial condition on the capacitor.

Thus, the answer given for \$v_o (t)\$ in the original example is correct and includes the initial condition.

Comment: I think you missed my comment above.  ```The function u(t) is undefined at t = 0. If you substitute t = 0 into that expression you would get 25u(0) which is not defined. ``` So can you show how the initial condition is included there?

Comment: u(t) = 1 at t =0

Comment: If you do that then you would get Vo(0) = 25u(0) = 25V which is obviously wrong!

Comment: Or another possibility is that the output voltage at t = 0 is equal to 5V and 25V at the same time.

Comment: At \$t=0^-\$ the capacitor is uncharged and looks like a short citrcuit. At \$t=0\$ an impulsive current of strength 2.5 A flows into the capacitor, charging the capacitor to 25 V (\$2.5 \times \frac{10}{s}=25V\$).

Comment: How would you explain output is 5V at t = 0 as what the problem gave?