# Initial current

Tags: passive-networks

In the following circuit, would the initial current used for the S domain transformation be i(-0)=0 or i(+0)=7/4, assuming the switch closes at t=0, taking into account i(-0)=i(+0)?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7xFgb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I don't know anything about S-domains but I do know that shorting out an ideal capacitor will cause an infinite current to flow. Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and **Save and Insert** on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: what do you mean by t=0 ? How long was V2 connected to the RLC network before the switch closes at t=0 ?

Comment: Note that i(-0) is not "formally" used. It is i(t<0) which is not the same thing. i(t>0) is also defined. i(t=0) is not really "defined", except for Heaviside function (where u(t<0)=0 and u(t>0)=1) and where u(0) =0.5 by definition (if one want).

Comment: read my answer in this post https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/621996/how-to-include-result-of-rc-circuit-at-t-0

Comment: Initial current, ok. But where ?

Answer (score 1):

Appart from the fact shorting a 500mF cap is not a good idea, the current delivered by the voltage source V2 at t=0 is equal to 0A (assuming V2 is connected a long time before t=0. Else, consider inrush current). At steady state, the inductance behaves like a short. The capacitor is charged to 7V and no current through R1 since there is no voltage drop across.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the input current when the switch is open is given by:

$$\text{I}_\text{i}\left(t\right)=\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}}{\text{s}}\cdot\left(\text{R}+\text{sL}+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\right)^{-1}\right]_{\left(t\right)}\tag1$$

Using the [final value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_value_theorem) [property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems) of the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform), we can conclude:

$$\lim_{t\space\to\space\infty}\text{I}_\text{i}\left(t\right)=\lim_{\text{s}\space\to\space0}\text{s}\cdot\frac{\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}}{\text{s}}\cdot\left(\text{R}+\text{sL}+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\right)^{-1}=0\tag2$$

**EDIT**

And for the voltage across the capacitor we know that:

$$\lim_{t\space\to\space\infty}\text{V}_\text{C}\left(t\right)=\lim_{\text{s}\space\to\space0}\text{s}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\cdot\frac{\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}}{\text{s}}\cdot\left(\text{R}+\text{sL}+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\right)^{-1}=\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}\tag3$$

---

**SECOND EDIT**

Now, let's solve this circuit after the switch is closed. We have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7EQOs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using KCL, we can see that:

$$\text{i}_1\left(t\right)=\text{i}_2\left(t\right)+\text{i}_3\left(t\right)\tag4$$

Using the voltage-current relations in the elements we can write:

- $$\text{v}_\text{i}\left(t\right)-\text{v}_1\left(t\right)=\text{i}_1\left(t\right)\cdot\text{R}_1\tag5$$
- $$\text{v}_1\left(t\right)-\text{v}_2\left(t\right)=\text{i}_2\left(t\right)\cdot\text{R}_2\tag6$$
- $$\text{i}_3\left(t\right)=\left(\text{v}_1'\left(t\right)-\text{v}_2'\left(t\right)\right)\cdot\text{C}\tag7$$
- $$\text{v}_2\left(t\right)=\text{i}_1'\left(t\right)\cdot\text{L}\tag8$$

The initial conditions are given by \$(2)\$ and \$(3)\$:

- $$\text{i}_1\left(0\right)=0\space\text{A}\tag9$$
- $$\text{v}_1\left(0\right)-\text{v}_2\left(0\right)=\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}\space\text{V}\tag{10}$$

Solving for \$\text{i}_1\left(t\right)\$ when \$\text{R}_2=0\$ and using your values we find:

$$\text{i}_1\left(t\right)=\frac{7\left(1-\exp\left(-4t\right)\right)}{4}\tag{11}$$